# Hibernate constraint already exists

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

i  need help to solve this hibernate  bug so every time i put a map annotation  in my entity i got this error,It tries to recreate some existing constraints.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PAYS")
public PrmPays getPrmPays() {
return this.prmPays;
}
public void setPrmPays(PrmPays prmPays) {
    this.prmPays = prmPays;
}
```

And this is the error !

```
  alter table ref_entite 
   add constraint FK4xutpn4uffubj8bfw92mmk30f 
   foreign key (id_pays) 
   references prm_pays     
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:999) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1890) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1855) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:304) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
```

here is my configuration in application.properties in spring boot

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  
hibernate.default_schema=db_default_schema_name
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  
security.basic.enabled=true  


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```